# Is this a reasonable use of special B in an imperial stout recipe?

Tags: extract, stout, specialty-grains, imperial

I've just worked up this (extract, specialty grains) recipe from glancing at clone recipes for old Rasputin imperial stout and black butte porter--they both have a smooth, chocolaty thing I'm going for as a base. But my goal is to bring the dark fruity flavors of a dubbel to the stout.

My question is about the grain bill. Does this seem balanced? I abhor too much coffee, bitter roast flavor in a stout, and I don't think it would go well with the dark fruit character. That said, I'm worried that I might be going overboard on the special B or chocolate malt, and am also wondering what folks think of the brown malt as a gentle base here.

If it matters, I'm doing some aroma hopping with Willamett, and fermenting with Irish yeast (and if this works out, I'll do a second batch with a belgian strain).

1 lbs                 Crisp Chocolate Malt (350.0 SRM)         Grain         2        8.3 %
1 lbs                 Special B Malt (180.0 SRM)               Grain         3        8.3 %
12.0 oz               Brown Malt (65.0 SRM)                    Grain         4        6.3 %
8.0 oz                Barley, Flaked (1.7 SRM)                 Grain         5        4.2 %
8.0 oz                Roasted Barley (300.0 SRM)               Grain         6        4.2 %
8 lbs 4.0 oz          Light Dry Extract (8.0 SRM)              Dry Extract   7        68.8 %

Comment: A pound of Special B is a LOT, but I've never used it in a stout. Perhaps its just the right amount to let a little raisin/prune flavor come through the roast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to minimize the roast character and are looking get that `smooth, chocolaty thing` you may want to use pale chocolate malt.  It is much smoother than regular chocolate malt.  However, if you up the fruit and reduce the roast, you may get a better reception by  calling the beer a black ale vs. a stout.  It sounds balanced based on your desired outcome, but not for the stout style.

cheers,